# Access to OnetoOneField relation model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have built a model for a user using the OnetoOneField(User). I have also added another field called keys.

```
class AppUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    key = models.CharField(max_length= 32, default="")

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Now after logging in using a particular username, how do I access the key attribute for that username  in views.py file ?

Comment: What do you mean with the "*key attribute*"?

Comment: The "key" from AppUser Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AppUser`object will be an attribute of your `User` object

```
user.appuser.key
```

Comment: I got this error: name 'user' is not defined after trying user.AppUser.key

Comment: `AppUser` should be lowercase(ie `appuser`) as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Nobi22 from where you get `username`? Put this variable instead of `user`. There should be an object of `User` model.

Answer (score -1):

by default each `OneToOneField` or `ForeignKey` field, will be accessed through it's related name (in this case User).

You didn't defined any related_name field in your AppUser model for user field, so access it like below:

```
user.appuser_set.key
```

As you noticed it will be the lowercase of class name plus _.

Or you can add it in manually like this:

```
class AppUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='app_user')
    key = models.CharField(max_length= 32, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

and in your views.py codes or any other place, access to AppUser from `user` like this:

```
user.app_user      # This will get app_user connected to user instance
user.app_user.key  # this will get proper key value for that appUser of User
```

**Update:**
Also be noted that until you didn't create and AppUser instance for each user, executing `user.app_user` will raise error.

For this kind of situations, I usually create a signal which will be trigger on `post_save` of user. It means that right after the user is created, a new instance of AppUser will be created for that user.

Comment: when using user.appuser_set: error =  name 'user' is not defined and when using request.user.appuser_set: error = 'User' object has no attribute 'appuser_set'

Comment: `makemigrations` and `migrate` are applied?

Comment: I am sorry, i am  a little confuse, where do i add "user.appuser_set.key" this ?

Comment: It seems that you didn't run these commands. `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: No, I did that as soon as I created my Model. I ran these two commands

Comment: I updated the answer. be noted that you should create an app_user first for that user. like this: `AppUser.objects.create(user=request.user)` or use signals to automatically create it.

Comment: thank you for your help, your suggestion led me to signals and post_save, now it is working. Thanks And Cheers !!

Comment: any time my friend